# Microsoft  Action & Func 8 structure?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Ive been noticing that both `Action` and `Func` delegates , having the *specific  structure from 2 to  8* params  :

[image]
[image]

why did they open -  explicit counted - parameter types ? ( and if so  , why 8?)

what about if i have 10 params ?

### edit

dis-continuing the 8 tradition , 
tuple  has 7 ... ??

[image]

### edit2

in the SystemCore.Dll - there are the 1..16 params ver.

Comment: Because there's no vargs for generics and they need to draw the line somewhere? If your method has 10 parameters you'll have to pass them as a structure, or you probably need to refactor something anyway.

Comment: @rup i can answer you like : `If your method has 7 parameters you'll have to pass them as a structure,` .... , also i aksed, why 8 ?

Comment: Why do most cars have 4 seats? What if I want to take 5 passengers?

Comment: don't think there is any computational reason behind this, just architect/hystorical choice...

Comment: @Tigran thats exactly my question. I think only a person with the documentation near him - can answer that. (IMHO)

Comment: In .NET 4.0 there are 8 more Func delegates with up to 16 in arguments.

Comment: @Steven there is the 16 param ver . but its in fw 2. ive checked...

Comment: @Steven `public delegate void Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12, T13 arg13, T14 arg14, T15 arg15, T16 arg16)

 
Name: System.Action<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16> 
Assembly: System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0 
`

Comment: And let's not forget `Tuple<T1, T2, ..., T7>`

Comment: @HenkHolterman T7 ! `public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest> : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable, ITuple
`.. they do what they want ....!

Comment: 10 params = god object. refactor it.

Comment: @alex and what makes you think that  8 isnt ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Never said so. Personally, I split things up when I reach 3.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You referenced a Silverlight runtime :) On .NET 4, 9 - 16 lives in `System.Core` IIRC

Comment: @RoyiNamir: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402872.aspx. `Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>` is a .NET 4 thing (look at the supported platforms). I've checked using Reflector. .NET 3.5 only has `Func<T>` up to 4 input arguments and Action<T> up to 4 arguments.

Comment: @leppie i opened the system.core... again from 1..16... not from 9.. 16..:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If it was again 1 - 8, there would be a type name clash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > why did they open - explicit counted - parameter types ?

Because the language does not support a variable amount of Type parameters.

> > ( and if so , why 8?)

Because 4 should usually be enough.

> > what about if i have 10 params ?

Then you will have to add the following to your own code:

```
 delegate void Action<T1, T2, ... , T10> (T1 arg1, T2 arg2, ..., T10 arg10);
```

Comment: 9-16 exists in .NET 4. In `System.Core` I think.

Comment: @i also meant ( while didnt know it up to 16) what if i need 17 for example ...:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you need 17, you are clearly doing it wrong ;p Create a container class then.

Comment: @leppie i think i saw once a solution to merge some elements into shorter form....sound familiar ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Nope, closest to that would be a `Tuple` I guess. You can have 7 x 16 parameters theoretically. But again, that screams BAD DESIGN MAKE HULK ANGRY!

Comment: @leppie I know i know  , not every question is from my usages... some are just for knowledge....